# getting data from file

Tags: java, android

I made an Android app that  loads a XML file from my website but it just loads the file one time only. I want it to load it as long as the app is running - should I use onResume, or just loop it in "onCreate" method?

Further, what does onResume do?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    while(true) {

        DocumentBuilder DB = DBF.newDocumentBuilder();

        URL url = new URL("website");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();                     
        Document D =DB.parse(connection.getInputStream());
    }   
}
```

Comment: do i re load the file if it is not exists in OnResume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish that is to set a global var to point to the XML, initialize it in onCreate, then check to make sure it exists in OnResume.

You might find this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle useful